# Swift how to get only date from Timestamp?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, date, timestamp

I am trying to only print the date from when an account is created in Firebase.

I can access the timestamp with:

```
Auth.auth().currentUser?.metadata.creationDate
```

That shows:

```
2021-01-10 14:05:36 +0000
```

I only want the date like:

```
2021-01-10
```

or even better

```
January 2021
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You have a `Date`, you want a `String` from it? => `DateFormatter`. Have you looked for that?

Comment: You should not determine how the user will display a date on their device. Check DateFormatter's method called  [setLocalizedDateFormatFromTemplate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/dateformatter/1417087-setlocalizeddateformatfromtempla) and pass `"yyyyMMMM"` when creating the date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
guard let date = Auth.auth().currentUser?.metadata.creationDate else { return }
let df = DateFormatter()
df.dateFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd" // For January 2021 make it MMMM yyyy
print(df.string(from:date))
```